# How to toggle setInterval in a child via state that was passed from parent component as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Complete working example at jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/tepedepozi/1/edit?console,output

_____________________________________________________________--

I have a component named App and the full returned JSX is here:

```
 <main style = {mainContainer}>  
   <Loader/>
   <section style={goldPanel}>
     <TimeDisplay isPlaying = {this.state.isPlaying}/>
     <div className="buttonContainer">
     <Button buttonText = {this.state.recordButtonText} onClick={this.toggleRecording}/> 
     <Button buttonText = {this.state.playButtonText} onClick={this.toggleSongPlaying} />
      </div>
   </section>
 </main>
```

Notice there are two buttons: a record button and a play button

When then the user clicks the play button:

```
<Button buttonText = {this.state.playButtonText} onClick={this.toggleSongPlaying} />
```

a method is invoked that changes `this.state.isPlaying` to `true`:

If the user clicks th record button it does not change `this.state.isPlaying` at all - ever ! This is how I programmed it and it is the behavior I want !

In the `TimeDisplay` component I pass the state of `this.state.isPlaying` as a prop.

```
<TimeDisplay isPlaying = {this.state.isPlaying}/>
```

The problem is that I want to program TimeDisplay to behave in ways that are based on this state, and the TimeDisplay component should only respond to the state change based on users clicking:

```
<Button buttonText = {this.state.playButtonText} onClick={this.toggleSongPlaying} />
```

However, when the user clicks the play button *and then* the record button the record button forces a rerender on the TimeDisplay component. I demonstrate the problem by placing a setInterval in the `startCount()` method code below.

The TimeDisplay component:

```
class TimeDisplay extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

    }

    startCounter(){

        if(this.props.isPlaying){
            console.log("counter working");  // runs no matter what button is clicked after play button
            setInterval(()=>{                
                console.log("Multiple setIntervals get invoked when user clicks record...not good"); 
            },1000)
        }
    }



    render() {

        this.startCounter()                //______Due to rerender. How to fix ? 

        return (
            <div>   
            <p><span id="seconds">00</span>:<span id="tens">00</span></p>
          </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: Do clear the timer before triggering new. Refer @shubham and my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write `this.startCounter()` function in your componentDidMount method and not in the render since the setInterval will do the job for you and you only have to call the setInterval once and not on every render. Now that isPlaying is received from props, you need to also update your child counter. You can do that in componentDidUpdate like

```
class TimeDisplay extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.interval = null;

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.startCounter();

    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if(prevProps.isPlaying !== this.props.isPlaying) {
            this.startCounter();
        }

    }
    startCounter() {

        if (this.props.isPlaying) {

            this.interval = setInterval(() => {
                console.log("Multiple setIntervals get invoked when user clicks record...not good");
            }, 1000);

        }else{

           clearInterval(this.interval);
        }
    }


    render() {


        return (
            <div>   
            <p><span id="seconds">00</span>:<span id="tens">00</span></p>
          </div>
        )
    }

}

class Button extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (<button onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.buttonText}</button>)
    }
}
```

**[Working JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/telinipobu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)**

> P.S. I have used `componentDidUpdate` instead of
>   `componentWillReceiveProps` because React has proposed that they will
>   rename `componentWillReceiveProps` from `v16.3.0` onwards and remove
>   it from v17.  Check [**this**](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/6/files/7042a2abcbdc90b4a7784ea6a753ce9abac169d9#diff-5e06005dbc26fcac5989745eaca87e80) conversation

Comment: one of the best practice can be to check setInterval already running or null. If not null cancel it before triggering new.

Comment: I need to start and stop the set interval when the user clicks the play button. I'll play with your code - I haven't yet

Comment: @Willian, you can call the startCounter function when the button is clicked and provide a check for clearing an interval

Comment: I don't think I am understanding you. When the user clicks the play button the set interval should begin playing. It doesn't. What do I need to do ?

Comment: Where is the Button component, is it in TimeDisplay

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri if clear interval check is added, even though this.startCounter()   is called from render it will not cause any issue and will solve OP problem. Else `componentWillrecvProps` method needed to call `this.startCounter()  ` on props changes.

Comment: @Ved, The render function may be called for a variety of reasons and to call startCounter on every render doesn't seem the right way to me

Comment: Yeah. in this case `componentWillReceiveProps` is the only  way.

Comment: Full working example: http://jsbin.com/tepedepozi/1/edit?console,output

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri  I made a jsbin above with working code to make the problem more clear.

Comment: Dang you're fast. GIve me a sec

Comment: @Ved, no componentWillReceiveProps is no longer a right place to check for updated props, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel the interval before triggering new. Also @shubham suggested do call `startCounter` method like he suggested.

```
  constructor(props) {
        super(props)
     this.timeInterval = null; 
      }
   }

   componentWillUnmount(){
           if(this.timeInterval != null){
            clearInterval(this.timeInterval)// Clear interval on page unmount
      }
    }

   startCounter(){
         if(this.timeInterval != null){
                clearInterval(this.timeInterval)// Cancel interval if it is being executing.
          }
            if(this.props.isPlaying){

                console.log("counter working");  // runs no matter what button is clicked after play button
          this.timeInterval  = setInterval(()=>{                
                    console.log("Multiple setIntervals get invoked when user clicks record...not good"); 
                },1000)
            }
        }

   componentDidMount() {
     this.startCounter()       // Call on initial render   
   }

   componentWillReceiveProps(){
      this.startCounter() //call on props change
     }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>   
            <p><span id="seconds">00</span>:<span id="tens">00</span></p>
          </div>
        )
    }

}
```